# How to set/choose what version of boost should be included?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, default

How to set/choose what version of boost should be included?

I am running ubuntu 14.04,and I use eclipse luna to build my project.

ubuntu 14.04 has a ready-made boost in /usr/lib.

But I want to use boost1.55 built by myself which is located in /usr/local/boost1.55.

I have no idea how to let eclipse build my project with  boost1.55 .

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways, the easiest is use static linked version of boost. By add the archive as `Other Objects` under `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous`, for example /usr/local/lib/libboost-system-155.a.